# Using worksheet codenames for sheets added at runtime in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For various reasons I prefer to use codenames to refer to worksheets in VBA code.

However, when I dynamically add a sheet like this (to a workbook that has just 1 sheet):

```
Sub example()

    Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    'SOME OTHER CODE HERE
    Sheet2.Activate

End Sub
```

... it won't compile because `Sheet2` isn't defined as a variable.

Is there a way around this? At the moment I am reverting to using the sheet name:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

Is there a way to do it using the codename?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a great idea to use codenames in VBA for sheets that exist at compile time. As you know, it allows you to refer to the sheet even if a user changes its name.

However, it's harder to do at runtime. You can do it using VBAProject Properties, if the user has granted access to the VBA project object model. But you can accomplish what you want, ongoing user-proof access to the sheet, simply by setting a `WorkSheet` variable:

```
Sub example()
Dim NewWorkSheet1 as Excel.Worksheet

Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set Newworksheet1 = ActiveSheet
'SOME OTHER CODE HERE

End Sub
```

Note that after adding a `WorkSheet` it is the `ActiveSheet`.

Also, you can declare the WorkSheet as a project- or module-level variable, if that level of scope is required.

Comment: Nice solution - it accomplishes what I want (which as you guessed was user-proofing). Thanks.